# расскажите , пожалуйста, что нам дают эти i++ и i-- в этой задаче?

Tags: java

расскажите , пожалуйста, что нам дают эти i++ и i--  в этой задаче ?
которые вы условиях else if

```
package com.javarush.task.task07.task0716;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("роза"); // 0
        list.add("лоза"); // 1
        list.add("лира"); // 2
        list.add("вода"); // 3
        list.add("упор"); // 4
        list.add("лора"); // 5
        list = fix(list);

        for (String s : list) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }

    public static ArrayList<String> fix(ArrayList<String> list) {
        //напишите тут ваш код
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size (); i++) {
            if(list.get (i).contains ("р") && list.get (i).contains ("л")){

            }else if(list.get (i).contains ("р")){
                list.remove (list.get (i));
                i++;
            }else if(list.get (i).contains ("л")){
                list.add (i,list.get (i));
                i--;
            }else {

            }
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: За такие вещи бьют по рукам!!!!

Comment: да не говори. не уж то

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`i++` нужно для того, чтобы не случилось исключение `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` (при удалении последнего элемента счетчик цикла увеличится, но элемента с таким номером уже не будет. Поэтому увеличиваем счетчик дополнительно, чтобы завершить цикл). *С другой стороны, цикл можно завершить и другим способом, а при таком решении в середине списка будут пропускаться элементы. Но другой пользы от i++ я придумать не могу*.

`i--` чтобы только что добавленный элемент тоже прошёл через if-else.

Answer (score 0):

i++ пропустить следующий цикл,
i-- возвращает цикл назад. (Повторяет)

Comment: но зачем? поподробней можно?